# Перезапуск activity на 8 android

Tags: android, single-activity

Проблема такая: Single Activity приложение, Hilt, Navigation Component. В приложении можно переключать язык между двумя. Такая кнопка есть на первом фрагменте, который видит незарегистрированный пользователь.  При нажатии на кнопку меняется локаль приложения (с этим все хорошо) и пересоздается MainActivity через

```
finish()
startActivity(intent)
```

На этой же странице есть два эдита (грубо говоря логин/пароль). После воссоздания фрагмента поля пустые. Пробовал: onSaveInstanceState - bundle теряется, viewModel - пересоздается. Единственное, что сработало это отправить данные в `startActivity(intent)` и получить в новой Activity, но по мне решение так себе.
Также пробовал метод `recreate()`. С ним данные сами подставляются и все хорошо. Однако на 8 android перестает работать клавиатура. По клику на EditText ставится фокус, но клавиатура не поднимается. Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с подобным и как решали?